# What does the following Verilog code realize

Tags: verilog

I was learning verilog hardware description language. I was confused a bit with the blocking and non-blocking statements. **Can someone tell me what the following verilog codes realize** and simple hints how

```
always@(posedge clk)
begin
   q1=d;
   q2<=q1;
   q3=q2;
end

always@(posedge clk)
begin
   q1<=d;
   q2<=q1;
   q3=q2;
end
```

These are two different codes implemented separately. I think FF comes into the picture because of edge detection. But I don't understand what it realizes as it has a intermix of blocking and non-blocking statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with d=0 q1=1 q2=2 q3=3.

```
always@(posedge clk)
begin
   q1=d;
```

q1 immediately gets the value of d=0.

```
   q2<=q1;
```

Non-blocking assignment: save the current value of q1 (which is currently the same as d=0)

```
   q3=q2;
```

q3 gets the *unchanged* value of q2, =2

```
end
```

At this point the nonblocking assignment happens and q2 gets the value 0.

I'm assuming the next always block is in a different module; putting it in the same module will just cause further confusion as you're overwriting the same variables again.

Start with d=0 q1=1 q2=2 q3=3 again.

```
always@(posedge clk)
begin
   q1<=d;
   q2<=q1;
```

Queue assignment of q1 to 0 and q2 to 1. These happen at the end of the block.

```
   q3=q2;
```

Set q3 to the current value of q2, ie 2.

```
end
```

Finally set q1=0 and q2=1.

Generally it's bad style to mix = and <= in the same block, and generally for synthesis you should always use <=. '=' can be helpful in testbenches where it behaves more like a conventional imperative programming language.

Comment: Actually this was a question asked by Freescale Semiconductor company under recruitment process but using its equivalent VHDL. Can you help me by giving the circuit that the above two codes realize

Comment: Can you clarify? You're applying for a job, and someone asked you this question? So you'll be turning this answer in to the interviewer?

Comment: In the process of interview I was posed with this question and I was not able to crack it. Now I was trying to overcome my mistakes